# VBA : Assign default value to a form control combo box

Tags: excel, combobox, form-control, vba

I am trying to display the text **Select** by default in a form control `combo box`. I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work. Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Option 1:

```
 Activesheet.shapes("choose_selection").text = "Select your choice"
```

Option 2:

```
 Activesheet.shapes("choose_selection").controlformat.text = "Select your choice"
```

but I get this error

[image]

Comment: did you figure out solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Set the default value in a combo box**

The ListIndex property sets the currently selected item using an index number. ListIndex = 1 sets the first value in the array.

```
Sub ChangeSelectedValue()
  With Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Combo Box 1")
  .List = Array("select your choice","Apples", "Androids", "Windows")
  .ListIndex = 1
 End With
End Sub
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately didn't work. Possible for you to share the exact piece of code with which you could run this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try first defining the `DropDown` object, and later on display the text in it.

**Note**: `DropDown` is the VBA object that refers to `Form_Control ComboBox`.

```
Dim drpdown As DropDown

' set the drop-down object
Set drpdown = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("choose_selection")

' modify the drop-down properties
With drpdown
    .Text = "Select your choice"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But this keeps on adding the same value "Select your choice" in the drop down again and again. How can I avoid that ?